# SSRS in Visual Studio 2008: Relative image paths?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, report

I have a header image that needs to be repeated in the header of multiple reports. I am aware that you can add an image to a report and point to a path where the image file reside, like `file://C:\path\to\Reports\Images\logo.gif`, but that path can and will change when the app is deployed.

I tried using a relative path like (assuming the reports are in the `Reports/` folder) `Images/logo.gif` (or `Images\logo.gif`), but this just produces a broken image both in the designer and on the actual output. Is my syntax incorrect? If not, is there a way to do something like this?

EDIT: I also know about embedding an image into a report, but then this image would need to be embedded into every report, and if it needed to be changed, it would have to be changed individually in every report.

Comment: What type of reports? Crystal?

Comment: SQL Reporting Services, I think it's called? The other non-Crystal kind of report you can make in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we ended up doing was described in [this blog post](http://www.haveyougotwoods.com/archive/2009/01/28/relative-path-to-an-external-image-in-reporting-services.aspx). We decided it was Good Enough of a solution, even if the path is, for now, hard-coded in there.

Answer (score 1):

Store the path in a variable in your database, and only keep the field name for each image in your table.  Put them together when running your app.

So, you'll have a table with images:

```
record1 otherdata image1.gif
record2 otherdata image2.gif
```

and another table that has system variables, including

```
imagepath  c:\path\to\reports\images\
```

Comment: Sorry, I clarified my question. The image is not part of the report data; it's only a logo in the header.

Comment: Ok, but can't you still store the path in the database?  So when the report is regenerated, it will check and use the current instance of the path?  However, since I don't use SQL Reporting services, I don't know how that works.

Answer (score 0):

We have dynamic header logos. We just store the images in the db, its easier this way. The logos are small enough they don't create much of a performance hit.

Image property on the Image control:

```
=First(Fields!BlobData.Value, "spimGetReportImg")
```

**spimGetReportImg Dataset** just calls the Stored Procedure we use to get the right image. IE:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spimGetReportImg]
@pk
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT b.BlobData
FROM   dbo.tblBlob b
WHERE  pkBlob = @pk
```